# Definition of Measure of an Interval

Tags: real-analysis

This is an exercise from "An Introduction to Measure Theory: T. Tao".

For any interval $I$, the length of the interval $I$ is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} |(I\cap \frac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z})|$ where $|\,\, |$ denotes the cardinality, and $\frac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}$ is the set $\{\frac{z}{n}\colon z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

I couldn't find any direction to prove this.

Also, can we generalize this to define the measure of $I_1\times I_2 \times \cdots I_n\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Hint. Can you list all elements of $(a,b) \cap \frac{1}{N}\Bbb Z$?

Answer (score 2):

Lets say the interval $I$ is open. Then

$$ |(I\cap  \frac 1 N \mathbb Z)| = \left\lfloor (b-a)N \right\rfloor.$$

Note that $\left\lfloor (b-a)N \right\rfloor \in  \left](b-a)N-1,(b-a)N\right]$.

Because $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} ((b-a)N-1) = \lim b-a - \frac 1 N = b-a$$ and $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} (b-a)N = b-a$$ it follows that $$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \left\lfloor (b-a)N \right\rfloor = b-a.$$

Comment: Can you explain a bit the statement "Note that ..."?

Comment: $y = \lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function: $y$ is the greatest integer less or equal than $x$. So if we 'round down' $x$ to the next lower integer, this integer must be in $[x-1,x]$ since first $y \leq x$ and second $x-y<1$.